# Azure web app not allowing users to login

Tags: c#, azure, azure-webapps

I have created a web application, an SQL Server and an SQL Database for my web app in Microsoft Azure Platform.The SQL server is not running on a VM it is just using the SQL Database Service. When I publish my site as a web application from Visual Studio I can log in to the website but when I try to log in again later from the same PC or another one I can't. It seems like it can't connect properly to the database so I tested the same thing in localhost while i was connected to the Azure Database and everything is working properly, so it shouldn't be a problem in my code or the database. Should I change something on the web application properties at the azure portal so it will work properly or should I change something in my code? My subscription is Academic, I don't know if that makes a difference.

Comment: You really need to edit your question with specific details. Otherwise there's nothing we can do to help. You haven't even explained *how* you are running your website: Virtual Machine? Web App? Web Role? Also: Please clarify whether you're actually running SQL Server in a VM, or using SQL Database service.

Comment: I added more information to the post as you asked I hope this will help you to understand my problem better. Thank you for your help.